# Cannot test payment via personal test paypal account created with paypal sandbox (also email appears not to be recognised at paypal.com public site)

Tags: testing, authentication, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

**Background**

I need to be able to test payments made via public paypal.com using a "dummy" personal paypal.com account created via the PayPal Sandbox tools: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts
- here I created a Business Merchant Account (where the payment will be sent to) and also a Personal account (which I want to use to make the payment on the usual paypal.com public site.

**The Problem**

The problem is that the email address and password that I set up the sandbox personal account do not work on the public paypal.com site as I would expect - paypal.com reports the standard login failure. It also seems that the email address is not recognised - when I click the forgot password link and enter the same email, it says email not found. Surprising given that this email was what I used to set up the personal paypal account via the sandbox.

**The question, summing up**

So What would I need to do to be able to use a PayPal-sandbox-created personal account to test payments made via the public paypal.com site?

**My Research on this problem so far**

I've looked around already for existing answers - on SO and via google...

- [PayPal accounts, testing and sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367818/paypal-accounts-testing-and-sandbox) (this doesn't help me - I tried the accepted answer about using a stronger password with special character but no difference)
- [how to login https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ in personal test account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630776/how-to-login-https-www-sandbox-paypal-com-in-personal-test-account) ( the answer here doesn't help me as it's just a stock answer of instructions - doesn't actual help the asker - and the asker's problem isn't quite the same as my problem )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :) Happy to be answering my own question: the working solution is to use www.sandbox.paypal.com in the form action when testing, instead of www.paypal.com

As per page 27 of:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf

It says:

> IMPORTANT: To execute test transactions on Sandbox you need to
>   complete a purchase as a  test buyer with your buyer test account.
>   Typically, you go through your  website purchase flow as a buyer. You
>   must ensure that you execute your test  on www.sandbox.paypal.com
>   instead of www.paypal.com

So, for example, the snippets of code for your paypal button would look something like:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

but still use just paypal.com for the action button (as the image is not available on www.sandbox.paypal.com):

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
```

Don't forget to change the form action to use www.paypal.com when you go live!

Obviously the pre-requisites are to setup a dummy merchant and dummy buyer account - as I described in my question - this is still valid and my steps should work.

If it doesn't work - i.e. login fails for example, clear out your browser data entirely. I had this problem and cleared everything - cookies history etc. and it worked.
See related question here: [paypal sandbox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476607/paypal-sandbox-not-working)

(as this answer works, I will be accepting it when I am allowed to do so).

Comment: This was the solution for my problem!

Comment: Aside from the fact that this doesn't work, why on earth wouldn't the button code be formatted correctly when created in the sandbox seller account? Is Paypal really that dumb?

Answer (score 0):

Just clearing cookies worked for me. By the way there was 44 cookies